# Is torsion subgroup of elliptic curve birationally invariant?

Tags: abelian-groups, elliptic-curves

It's probably a very basic question: Having two birationally equivalent elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ - is the torsion subgroup unchanged under the birational equivalence?

Comment: I think that two birationally equivalent abelian varieties need to be isomorphic

Comment: That's the thing Im not sure: whether groups of two birationally equivalent abelian varieties are isomorphic, or whether at least the torsion subgroups are.

Comment: According to theorem 3.8 in Milne's notes on AV, any birational map $A\to B$ extends to an isomorphism of AV, so it also preserves the group structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two birationally equivalent, projective curves without singularities are isomorphic. Hence two birationally equivalent elliptic curves are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

The *group structure* of the torsion subgroup may be the same, but the group law may look very different! I find the following example to be interesting and related to your question.

Let $E:y^2=x^3+1$ with zero at $[0,1,0]$, and consider $E':y^2=x^3+1$ where we now declare zero to be $[2,3,1]$. Then, $E$ and $E'$ are clearly birationally equivalent via the identity map but zero in $E$ does not map to zero in $E'$. Nonetheless, their torsion subgroup is both $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, but the group law is different.

For instance, let $P=[-1,0,1]$ and $Q=[0,1,0]$, then
$$P+_E Q = [2,-3,1]$$
while
$$P+_{E'} Q = [0,-1,0].$$